# How to increase websocketMaxFramePayloadLength in HttpClientConfiguration

Tags: spring, netty, spring-websocket, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

I am creating Spring Api Gateway. One of the microservice behind use websockets to communicate with clients. When mentioned microservice returns data to the Gateway I am getting `io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.CorruptedWebSocketFrameException: Max frame length of 65536 has been exceeded.`

I have extended the GatewayAutoConfiguration's bean webSocketService and set the maxFramePayloadLength property through ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy. I also created custom 
ReactorNettyWebSocketClient and override method `execute` to change ReactorNettyWebSocketSession's parameters. Unfortunately, it did not help.

I have found that maxFramePayloadLength property in HttpClientConnect is provided by HttpClientConfiguration and changes I have made have no effect.

Is there a way to change the default value of maxFramePayloadLength?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify this as a property in your `application.properties`/`application.yml` file, there is no need to modify anything else.

`spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.websocket.max-frame-payload-length`

For reference this is the list with the [Spring Cloud Gateway properties](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/appendix.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have this property set with random value but it doesn't work.